# Rhino.Commons with StructureMap

Tags: structuremap, rhino-commons

Has anybody tried to use StructureMap for IoC with Rhino.Commons?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windsor is deeply rooted in Rhino Commons, a search for "Windsor" in the source code gives back 45 files. Binsor, for example, is **very** specific to Windsor. However, it shouldn't be very difficult to refactor **some parts** of Rhino.Commons to use [CommonServiceLocator](http://www.codeplex.com/CommonServiceLocator) instead of Windsor, effectively making it container-provider-independent.

It's unlikely that you want **all** of Rhino.Commons, so my question to you is: what part(s) of Rhino.Commons do you need?

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, I was looking to use Rhino.Security and repository to implement a role based access MVC app.

Comment: Were you able to use it with StructureMap? IIRC there's a recent thread on the mailing list about using CommonServiceLocator.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the source code I don't see how it would be possible. The IoC.Initialize() method takes in an IWindsorContainer.